# Selection cursor in the wrong place

Tags: bug, ios-app

If you select some text in the body of the question (edit mode) and go to the [layered view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287601/339911) you may see part of selection cursor (blue half of a circle) in the left top corner:

[image: cursor]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Comment: In iPhone, same problem occurs when I swipe right to back to question list while selecting some text in the body.