# Selection cursor in the wrong place (2)

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new question
2. Add several lines into the body to make scrolling possible
3. Add a title and select text on it
4. Scroll slightly down and stop when title will go over top bar (where Cancel and Submit buttons)

> [image: cursor]

Possibly related to another bug reported as [Selection cursor in the wrong place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287622/339911).

- App Version: 1.6.3.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: This appears to be a system wide problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vxts.png

Comment: One solution is to get a mini bluetooth mouse.  With that, you can paint the section you want highlighted.